# Circles and lines on the complex plane correspond to circles on Riemann sphere.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I need to prove that **circles and lines on the complex plane correspond to circles on Riemann sphere**.

This is intuitively easy to understand, as lines on the complex plane can be viewed as a circle going through the point $\infty$. But the thing is, how to describe a circle on Riemann sphere? How to make sure that circles and lines map to circles instead of ellipses or other shapes? So I need some features to determine that the images under this projection are indeed circles.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps start with the intersection of the sphere with a plane being a circle.  Three noncolinear points determine a plane, so...

Comment: @hardmath, Great! It is indeed brilliant to describe circles on Riemann sphere with the intersection of a plane. And I have just found out that this was exactly what Ahlfors did to prove it in his *Complex Analysis*. Thank you! :-)

Comment: There is a fascinating connection here with [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), but we can leave that topic for another time.

Comment: Have you heard about **stereographic projection** (from one of the poles of the sphere to its equatorial plane ? See [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/StereographicProjection.shtml) or [there](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-01a/montgomery/index.html) (fourth figure).

Comment: @JeanMarie When OP said “map,” I presume the map was stereographic projection. Rather vague.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah what I mean here is stereo graphic projection